# How to use tools in Single Player Commands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I have recently installed Single Player Commands into my Minecraft. I am trying to use the wand tool and the brush tool, but neither of them are working. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: I think those are a part of WorldEdit, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You also need to install World Edit. If you use the automatic installer it should do this for you but if you did it manually, the WorldEdit.jar needs to go into the bin folder in your .minecraft directory (NOT in the minecraft.jar). I would need more information about your problem if you want a more specific answer.

Comment: I believe WE is a bukkit mod.

Comment: @Chipperyman it is but it can also be downloaded to be used with Single Player commands to be used in single player.